# ColdFusion / Shibboleth - REMOTE_USER

Tags: iis, coldfusion, cgi, saml, shibboleth

I have a ColdFusion application being hosted on my IIS server. I added the [Shibboleth](https://www.switch.ch/aai/guides/sp/installation/) service to my web IIS, and the CGI/Filters are setup to use it. I added my application to the [testshib](http://www.testshib.org/) federation and was able to login successfully. Now I'm trying to get the session variable into the ColdFusion code.

When I dump the CGI scope, I see the shibboleth session is saved under `HTTP_COOKIE`, but `REMOTE_USER` is an empty string. This is because `REMOTE_USER` cannot be used according to the [docs](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess#NativeSPAttributeAccess-REMOTE_USER). Instead the request header variable should be named `HTTP_REMOTE_USER`, but I don't see that in the CGI dump. Does anyone why this is? Do I have to set that up my shibboleth attribute-map or in ColdFusion ?

index.cfm

```
CGI dUMP
<cfdump var = "#cgi#" > 
<br>HTTP_REMOTE_USER
<cfdump var="#CGI.HTTP_REMOTE_USER#">
<br>Get Request
<cfset x = GetHttpRequestData()> 
<cfdump var="x">
```

Dump result

```
HTTP_COOKIE:_shibsession_64656487474733a2f2f6465736f6d2f73686962626f6c657468=_ecb60f7e4bf7616ab3522;
```

Session

```
Miscellaneous
Session Expiration (barring inactivity): 479 minute(s)
Client Address: 224.61.30.228
SSO Protocol: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol
Identity Provider: https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth
Authentication Time: 2017-11-30T14:48:48.255Z
Authentication Context Class: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
Authentication Context Decl: (none)

Attributes
affiliation: 2 value(s)
entitlement: 1 value(s)
eppn: 1 value(s)
persistent-id: 1 value(s)
unscoped-affiliation: 2 value(s)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that ColdFusion doesn't expose every possible CGI variable in the `<cfdump>`, only the most common ones.  That doesn't mean you can't access what appear to be missing CGI variables directly.  Try changing your dump to specifically target the one you need, like:

`<cfdump var="#CGI.HTTP_REMOTE_USER#">`

If it still isn't being written to the CGI scope, you might be able to access that specific request header variable through the the page request using `getHTTPRequestData()`.

Comment: <cfdump var="#CGI.HTTP_REMOTE_USER#">  returns 
HTTP_REMOTE_USER : [empty string] . Along with getHTTPRequstData.  If i dump it via asp page it display HTTP_REMOTEUSER:myself@testshib.org .

Comment: Setting GetHttpRequestData to headers, somehow got it to work. Thanks, ill give you the bounty when its eligible in 2 days.

Comment: Sounds like something is getting dropped by the ColdFusion/IIS connector.  From this blog post, it looks like others have seen similar behavior in the past: http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/128v2r7gf4/custom-header-fields-are-missing-after-siteminder-redirect-unclassified

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve by adding useHeaders="true" to

`<ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true"  useHeaders="true">`

in shibboleth2.xml ... then dump getHTTPRequestData() to see your values.  I also had to modify attribute-map.xml to handle some of the values passed back my the iDP and I added NameID (we are using Azure AD) in shibboleth2.xml

```
 <ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://intranet.xxx.edu/shibboleth"
    REMOTE_USER="eppn subject-id pairwise-id persistent-id NameID"
    cipherSuites="DEFAULT:!EXP:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:!RC4:!3DES:!kRSA:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1:!TLSv1.1">
```